# custom repeating background image using css

Tags: html, css

[image]

my image is `1.` Normal repeat-x is `2.`

I need image repeat like this `3.`

Comment: I can only say wow!!!. But on a serious note can you combine 1 and 1' (inversion of 1) to form a image and simply repeat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with CSS. What you can do, however, is grab your favorite graphics editing program, and make this instead:

[image]

Use this with `repeat-x` to get what you want. See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/aPQHe/1

Comment: But my image is big. Not this image

Comment: @ebattulga Nope. Sorry, there's no other way. That's just how `background-repeat` works.

Answer (score 0):

Merge part 1 & 2 of your image 3 and set it as the image to be repeated.